# WCF Service inaccessable when attaching VS 2010 profiler

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, profiling, instrumentation

I'm receiving the following error after I attach the visual studio 2010 profiler to my wcf service.

> The requested service,
>   'net.tcp://host:port/path/myservice.svc'
>   could not be activated. See the
>   server's diagnostic trace logs for
>   more information.

The service works great otherwise, and as soon as I stop profiling, I can connect and use the service again.

The closest I could find to a similar situation online was [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/vstsprofiler/thread/2ecec82c-639b-4c77-bfd6-f2da8d267912?prof=required), but the Net.Tcp Listener Adapter does not stop on my server, and restarting it does not help either. Neither does an iisreset.

I'm receiving the following entry in the event log:

> Failed to initialize the
>   AppDomain:/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/MyService
>
> Exception: System.Web.HttpException
>
> Message: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'MyService' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to
>   load a program with an incorrect
>   format. InnerException:
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
>
> Message: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'MyService' or one of
>   its dependencies. An attempt was made
>   to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.
>
> InnerException:
>   System.BadImageFormatException
>
> Message: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'MyService' or one of
>   its dependencies. An attempt was made
>   to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

Does this sound like the profiler is creating a bad dll when instrumenting? If so, how would I get around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple issues at work here.
1) the binaries were being instrumented as 32 bit instead of 64 bit. This seemed to be a problem with the visual studio profiler, but also could have been a symptom of issue 2) I was attempting to profile remotely instead of on the physical machine which isn't supported.

I installed the command line tools on the test server and am looking to profile that way.